# Error in open-for-using statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

*im trying the dynamic cursor concept in my stored procedure in oracle* i used the stmt as below:

```
OPEN d for
            'select datetime,'|| v_paramname ||',tt from datasource where '|| v_vrformula ||' and  feederid=cast('||v_meterid||',varchar2(6)) and datetime>=:v_timeperiod' using v_timeperiod;
    LOOP
    FETCH d INTO V_dateval,V_value,V_dataid;
    EXIT WHEN d%NOTFOUND;
    INSERT INTO pseb.validationfailureaudit (MeterID,RuleID,DataType,Value,Dataid, TimePeriod,EditedValue,EditedTimePeriod,paramname) VALUES  (V_meterid,V_ruleid,V_datatype,V_value ,V_dataid,V_dateval,null, null,V_paramname);
    V_length:=V_length+1;
    END LOOP;
CLOSE d;
```

I m getting **missing keyword** error in **open** statement.

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Rather than open the cursor, output to the screen the final SQL statement you are constructing dynamically. You may well have a syntax error in it causing your `Missing keyword` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing as `AS` clause in the [`CAST`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions023.htm):

```
... and feederid=cast('||v_meterid||' AS varchar2(6)) ...
```